# What does word='word' and words=[] do in the following code?

Tags: ruby, variables, object, variable-assignment

I've been searching online. There are a lot of resources to explain the bigger concepts in the following code but not what the use and/or meaning is of the smaller details.  What does the first two lines mean?  (Also, I'm a beginner.)

```
    word = 'word'
    words =[]

    puts 'Please type as many words per line then press the Enter Key.'
    puts 'When you are finished press the Enter Key without typing anything.'
    while word != ''
    word = gets.chomp
    words = words.push word
    end
    puts ''
    puts 'Your original values:'
    puts words
    puts ''
    puts 'Your values sorted:'
    puts words.sort
    puts ''
```

Comment: `word = 'word'` and `words = []` initializes a default value for `word` and `words` respectively

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
word = 'word'
```

The part on the right initializes a new String object with the value `"word"`. The part on the left and the equals sign make the variable `word` a reference to that string. Informally, this line *assigns* the string `"word"` to the variable `word`.

Next:

```
words = []
```

The part on the right initializes a new Array object. Since there's nothing between the square brackets, this creates an empty array. It's equivalent to `Array.new`. As above, the part on the left and the equals sign make the variable `words` a reference to the array. In other words, this line assigns the Array object to the variable `words`.

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please explain the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I would appreciate the opportunity to improve it.